# Get Problems with sessions and multithreading (NHibernate Version 2)

Tags: c#, multithreading, session, nhibernate, sessionfactory

We have a old software and use NHibernate version 2 and Oracle DB. I changed some parts so that the software has now multi threads. After the change I got problems with multithreading and the session-object (because session-object is not thread safe).
So I change the SessionMananger class where session are created. Retrieving data from the database always a new session is created `session = SessionFactory.OpenSesion()`.
When storing data the session object will be stored and reuse until commit or rollback. After commit the session object will be closed.

The solutions is working but sometimes we get different errors like ORA-03135 or select query cant be executed.

Is it ok to open a session and dont close this session explicit. Or will the session be closed automatically?

Is it possible to store a session object in a thread safety dictionary with thread id as key?

Answer (score 0):

For every thread a create a session and safe this session in a ConcurrentDictionary with thread-id as the key and the session as value. When session is needed the app check if a session for the special thread was created. If not a new session will be created.

```
bool success = _DictThreadSession.TryGetValue(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, out session);

if (!success)
{
    //create session and run some stored procedures
    session = CreateSession();
    _DictThreadSession.TryAdd(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, session);
}
```